# mobilefirst native ios keychain wrapper issue

Tags: xcode, git, keychain, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I am working on a project for a native iOS app using xcode to develop the project, but including both MobileFirst Platform Foundation capabilities and mobile data capabilities from Bluemix. We are using a shared git repository on IBM DevOps services (jazzhub) to share project source code and work collaboratively on it.

Most of the native apps I have built in the past have been on my own, so this is my first attempt to collaborate using git/xcode working together.

All that is just context for the issue, which is a project using the above environment on my collegues mac build/runs fine. Once I git clone the project and try to run it on my mac I am getting the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], /tmp/builds/bld-00-20141218-1823-2824648/worklight-ios/framework-xcode-project/NativeSDK-Sources/WorkLight/KeychainItemWrapper.m:311
2015-01-31 13:16:27.657 IBMBankNativeApp[88827:11348297] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
```

Above this message in the xcode log I see a secussful initialization of the Bluemix and the call to initialize the MFP connection:

```
2015-01-31 13:16:27.439 NativeApp[88827:11348297] INFO: IBMBluemix initialization successful.
IBMBluemix SDK Version: 1.0.1.20141124-1240
BlueMix Target: https://mybank.mybluemix.net
applicationId: ea36d23f-....
2015-01-31 13:16:27.530 NativeApp[88827:11348297] IBMData SDK initialization successful.
2015-01-31 13:16:27.580 NativeApp[88827:11348297] ViewController - connectToServer - Initializing ...
2015-01-31 13:16:27.591 NativeApp[88827:11348297] [DEBUG] [WL_CONFIG] -[WLConfig init] in WLConfig.m:68 :: {
    "application id" = NativeiOSApi;
    "application version" = "1.0";
    environment = iOSnative;
    host = "192.168.0.17";
    platformVersion = "6.3.0.00.20141218-1823";
    port = 10080;
    protocol = http;
    wlServerContext = "/MFProject/";
    wlUid = "wY/mbnwKTDDYQUvuQCdSgg==";
}
```

Before the MFP callback for initialization of the connection the application terminates with the keychain error.

I did not add the keychain access to the project, I'm using cocoapods to set-up bluemix support and wonder if that somehow is adding the keychain support?

I tried removing and running, removing then re-adding they keychain support in the project capabilities, all with the same error.

Is there something checked in and replicated by git that shouldn't be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that the following Key exists under the Root key in both `entitlements-debug.plist` and `entitlements-release.plist`:

Key: keychain-access-groups
Type: Array

Inside the above Key:
Key: Item 0
Type: String
Value: $(AppIdentifierPrefix)worklight.group

[image]

Comment: Idan, Thank you! This solved the problem for me. I have a slightly different entitlements file, but your answer help to identify the problem.

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark as resolved when you can.