# Worklight 6.3 locked keychain when using Apple Watch

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, apple-watch, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I'm trying to retrieve data from an adapter secured with the device provisioning (set on auto).

Unfortunately when trying to call the adapter,if the device is locked, but the app has been started in background, I get errors of not being able to retreive the certificate due to the keychain lock.

Is there any way to solve this problem, without disabling the device provisioning?

Comment: can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930879/mobilefirst-ios-error-crashing-my-app/34938119#34938119

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Watch OS 1.0 or 2.0?

With watchOS 1.0 the watch extension is running actually on the iPhone. So if iPhone is closed the watch app will not work.

Comment: It's on watchOS 2.* the problem seems to be related to the fact that the data saved by Worklight are saved under a specific settings which makes them unaccessible if the keychain got locked. We changed the approach to the data we wanted to save in the meantime. But it would be nice if we will be able to use it. Thanks in advance.